# Yii2 get post request value not working

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Why `Yii::$app->request->post()` not working?

Form:

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

   <?= $form->field($model, 'parent')
        ->dropDownList($model->AuthItemDropdown
        );
    ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'child[]')
        ->dropDownList($model->AuthItemDropdown,
            ['multiple'=>'multiple']  
        );
    ?>
```

Controller:

```
 public function actionCreate(){

    $model = new AuthItemChild();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){

        $parent =  Yii::$app->request->post('parent');
        echo $parent; // show nothing

        $x = Yii::$app->request->post('child');
        print_r($x);// show nothing
        exit;
```

But output of `print_r(Yii::$app->request->post());` is:

```
Array
(
    [_csrf-backend] => OGd0emxoOHgJEh8ICFloPlYvJg8BEHk.VjVAMx0hTD9CKgIDNSdVOg==
    [AuthItemChild] => Array
        (
            [parent] => admin
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [0] => admin
                    [1] => create-branch
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your `print_r(Yii::$app->request->post());` output you should call for:

```
$authItemChild = Yii::$app->request->post('AuthItemChild');
echo $authItemChild['parent']; // should show 'admin'
```

Comment: and how I can count `child`?

Comment: `count($authItemChild['child'])`

Comment: yeah that's working fine, some time yii official doc take away from right direction like what they describe [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-requests.html)  and actual solution is different.

Comment: No, it's not, the description there is correct. `post()` is direct equivalent of $_POST variable.

Comment: @Bizley I have the same problem, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are loading the model with the post, I guess you should show the loaded results, instead of trying to get the post again:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){

    $parent =  $model->parent;
    echo $parent;

    $x = $model->child;
    print_r($x);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get value the same way. What i disclosed is
$app->request->post() (Yii2.0.10) works different with text and select fields.

1. Text fields are binded via `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())`
2. **For selects** better way is to get value as `$model->parent=$request->post("parent")` **with name explicitly set:** `<?= $form->field($model, 'parent')
       ->dropDownList($model->AuthItemDropdown,['id' => 'parent','name'=>'parent']
       );
   ?>`
   By default ActiveForm determine name as `YouModelName[NameOfField]`