# post request value not work

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to get **just one** post with using `Yii::$app->request->post()`.

For example I just want get `title` from posts.

Here is my code:

```
public function actionSearchResult() {
        $gets = Yii::$app->request->post('title');
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($gets);
        die();
    }
```

I added some more code as [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597229/yii2-get-post-request-value-not-working) says, but still I don't get the `title`.

```
public function actionSearchResult() {
            $gets = Yii::$app->request->post();
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($gets);
            echo '<br>';

            $values = Yii::$app->request->post('add');
            print_r($values);
            echo $values['link_type'];
            die();
        }
```

In result shows just bellow:

```
Array
(
    [_csrf] => OEktaXFCMEpnPx8ZFjBaLkkTTwcHFwcQaBFdXSl3Yn8PcX46JAMBBw==
    [Add] => Array
        (
            [title] => test
            [link_type] => 2
            [subject_id] => 1
            [is_public] => 0
            [province] => 
            [city] => 
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your array it's:

```
$values = Yii::$app->request->post('Add');
echo $values['title'];
```

Comment: you mean the problem  just was because **case sensitive**?